# Two-dimensional array: inner product compilation error

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to finish an assignment which requires me to write a function `double inner_product(const double *a, const double *b, int n)`, where `a` and `b` are pointers to array of length `n`. This function will find the inner product defined as $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 =a_i*b_i$, using only pointer arithmetic.

Below is the code that I came up with. It does not compile and gives an error. Can someone please help me fix this error and suggest any improvements to this code.

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10

double inner_product(const double *a, const double *b, int n)
{   int sum=0;
    int row= (int)&a;
    int column=(int)&b;
    const double ar[row][column];
    const double *p;

    for(p=&ar[0][0]; p<&ar[n][n]; p++) 
    {sum += *p;}

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
  const double *a, *b;
  int row= (int)&a; int column=(int)&b;
  int N;
  double x;
  const double *p, ar[row][column];

 printf("Enter the %d elements of each row and column seperated by a comma:\n",N);

 for(p=&ar[0][0];p<&ar[N][N];p++)
    {scanf("%d%d",&row, &column);}

 x=inner_product(a,b, N);

 printf("the inner product of the matrix is: %lf", x);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You've got `#define N 10` and then `int N;`.  The preprocessor converts that to `int 10;` which is a syntax error.

Comment: then should I simply say `int N=10;` instead of using the `define N 10`?

Comment: When you've fixed the obvious syntax error (delete the `int N;` line is probably simplest), then you've got memory allocation problems.  You need to rework the code in `main()` to ensure you are referencing allocated memory — or, rather, you need to allocate memory so that you can reference it.

Comment: You could use `int N = 10;` instead of `#define N 10`.  However, that requires support for VLAs (variable length arrays).  You still have all sorts of problems.  Converting addresses of pointers to integers to use the address as the dimension of an array is not going to work sanely.  And you can't initialize a const VLA, but you can't modify it after the declaration either.  There are problems galore in the code.

Comment: ... that's one reason why preprocessor macros should be in all capitals and other identifiers not.

Comment: you seem to expect this `int row= (int)&a;` gives you the size of the array pointed to? It doesn't ... it just gives you the memory location of your variable `a` (a pointer) converted to an integer, which is utterly meaningless.

Comment: In the `inner_product()` function, you are passed two 1D vectors of `double` values; you have to multiply corresponding elements of the arrays and sum those products.  Why on earth have you got a 2D array — that is uninitialized — in the `inner_product()` function? You need two 1D vectors in the main program that you initialize (by reading data). ***Start over.***  Get rid of all this code (create a sub-directory `junk` and move it into the sub-directory) and start from scratch.  It will be quicker than going through fixing this code.  You are making mountains out of molehills.

Comment: And there are many more of these horrible misconceptions, so you should better get a good book or other learning resource on C and start from the beginning ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, you need to start from the beginning again.  Here's a rewritten program that does the job.  The `inner_product()` function is moderately big simply because it has both debug printing code in it (commented out) and three alternative ways of doing the arithmetic (two of those commented out, too).  The core is extremely simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

static double inner_product(const double *a, const double *b, int n)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        /*printf("%8.3f * %8.3f = %14.6f  ", *a, *b, *a * *b);*/
        // Alternative ways of computing the sum
        // sum += *(a+i) * *(b+i);
        // sum += a[i] * b[i];
        sum += *a++ * *b++;
        /*printf("CS = %15.6f\n", sum);*/
    }
    return sum;
}

static void print_vector(const char *tag, const double *v, int n)
{
    printf("Vector %s (%d):\n", tag, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%9.3f", v[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    // random -n 10 -F '%7.3f' -- -1000 1000 | commalist -B 8 -n 5 -W 8
    double a[N] =
    {
         -78.533,   52.153, -632.825, -196.897,  157.031,
        -804.630, -787.420, -281.817, -963.641,  561.922,
    };
    double b[N] =
    {
         112.700,  -83.580, -294.587,  320.394,   -8.366,
         218.917,  148.115,  421.533, -691.338, -741.578,
    };

    print_vector("A", a, N);
    print_vector("B", b, N);

    double x = inner_product(a, b, N);
    printf("The inner product of the vectors is: %lf\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

The printing function is useful; you can devise variants that output a newline every five numbers, or any other number of numbers per line.  Printing the test data is important; it ensures that the program is processing the data you expect.

Output (debugging enabled):

```
Vector A (10):
  -78.533   52.153 -632.825 -196.897  157.031 -804.630 -787.420 -281.817 -963.641  561.922
Vector B (10):
  112.700  -83.580 -294.587  320.394   -8.366  218.917  148.115  421.533 -691.338 -741.578
 -78.533 *  112.700 =   -8850.669100  CS =    -8850.669100
  52.153 *  -83.580 =   -4358.947740  CS =   -13209.616840
-632.825 * -294.587 =  186422.018275  CS =   173212.401435
-196.897 *  320.394 =  -63084.617418  CS =   110127.784017
 157.031 *   -8.366 =   -1313.721346  CS =   108814.062671
-804.630 *  218.917 = -176147.185710  CS =   -67333.123039
-787.420 *  148.115 = -116628.713300  CS =  -183961.836339
-281.817 *  421.533 = -118795.165461  CS =  -302757.001800
-963.641 * -691.338 =  666201.641658  CS =   363444.639858
 561.922 * -741.578 = -416708.992916  CS =   -53264.353058
The inner product of the vectors is: -53264.353058
```

Output (debugging disabled):

```
Vector A (10):
  -78.533   52.153 -632.825 -196.897  157.031 -804.630 -787.420 -281.817 -963.641  561.922
Vector B (10):
  112.700  -83.580 -294.587  320.394   -8.366  218.917  148.115  421.533 -691.338 -741.578
The inner product of the vectors is: -53264.353058
```

I tested it by writing a script to drive `bc` to repeat the calculation; it gave the same answer (after I'd debugged the script).